# How to use ffmpeg removelogo filter

Tags: ffmpeg, image-processing

I am trying to use ffmpeg [removelogo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#removelogo) filter, there is no syntax error but result has some kind of weird magenta triangle where mask is applied.

I am using following command

```
ffmpeg -y -i sample_image.jpg -vf "removelogo=mask.png" test.jpg
```

Here are the files used in command.

[image: sample_image.jpg]
[image: mask.png]
[image: test.jpg]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a limitation of the filter. The removelogo filter uses the neighboring pixels to fill in the area containing the logo. Your mask extends to the very edge of the image leaving no neighboring pixels. For best results you need to leave some space.

Since logos usually do not extend to the edge of the image if using removelogo to remove an actual logo and leave enough space from the edge then you will not encounter this issue.

Alternatively, if you must extend to the edge you could try the [delogo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#delogo) filter instead, but it won't let you use an arbitrary mask; only rectangular coordinates. Or use a combination of [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad), [fillborders](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fillborders), and [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop), but results may not be satisfactory (I didn't try).

[image]
[image]
<sub>Original with ugly logo and "bird shit" mask with sufficient padding from edge.</sub>

[image]
<sub>Result of removelogo filter.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your help, I guess I have to use a hybrid solution from delogo and removelogo filter.

Comment: @ZainAli: don't need hybrid, `removelogo` does a more precise job. `delogo` does a similar job but with a (fixed) rectangular mask, which `removelogo` can also do.